# Why aren't my Backbone Route Events working?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events, backbone-routing

Can someone explain why `router.on("route:myTest", function(page) {});` does't work?

My `Backbone.Router`is as follows:

```
var MyRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        Backbone.history.start({ pushState:true, root:"/subdir/" });
    },
    routes: {
        '' : 'start',
        'base' : 'myTest',
        'base/:name': 'myTest',
        'base/:name/:skill': 'myTest',
        '*default': 'defaultRoute'
    },
    start: function(){
        alert('Chapter 5 route invoked');
    },
    defaultRoute: function(){
        alert('Router does not handle this route');
    },
    myTest: function(name,book){
        if(name !== undefined){
            if(book !== undefined){
                alert([name, 'is reading', book].join(' '));
            }else{
                alert('Saying hello to ' + name);
            }
        }else{
            alert('Saying hello!');
        }
    }
});
```

Here is the code on my html page:

```
function showBook(name){
    console.log('Show book ' + name);
    router.navigate('book/' + name);
}
router.on("route:myTest", function(page) { showBook('TestBook'); });
```

Answer (score 0):

`Backbone.Router` doesn't trigger events of just the route name (`myTest` in this case). If you look at [the docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog) you can see that the router triggers the `route`, `route:[name]` events, so you should use the following instead:

```
router.on('route:myTest', function(){});
```

That event will be fired if the route matches `base`, `base/:name`, `base/:name/:skill` which may or may not be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did use `'route:myTest'`, my initial post was a typo. Sorry, that was my mistake. I've updated my post to reflect my actual code (at the bottom)